# PHP file_put_contents() function fails after a drive is unmounted/remounted

Tags: php, macos, nas

I have a CLI PHP script running on an OSX system that saves files to a connected NAS drive. If the NAS is unmounted then remounted, the `file_put_contents()` function fails and returns the error:

> Warning: file_put_contents(/Volumes/XXX/XXX.file) [/phpmanual/function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I'm clearing the file cache with `clearstatcache()` before the write. The drive is clearly mounted.

Restarting the script does not help. The only thing so far that works is to restart the machine.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to get PHP to 're-recognize' the connected volume?

Comment: does the `XXX` stuff ever change? e.g. on mount #1 it's `/Volumes/abc/foo.bar`, but on mount #2, it's actually `/Volumes/def`?

Comment: No, the mount point is always the same. The rest of the file path is different obviously.

Comment: start doing some debugging, do a chain of `is_dir`, `is_writeable`, etc... on the components on the path, and see where things blow up.

Comment: What happens if you restart Apache, rather than the computer? Just trying to narrow down the problem, it could be Apache.

Comment: I did try restarting Apache as well, with no success. I am running the script from the command line BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some serious digging, I figured out that it has to do with the filesystem and not PHP. I solved it by running the following commands:

```
exec('mkdir /Volumes/Mount_Point;
    mount_afp afp://user:pass@192.168.0.X/Mount_Point /Volumes/Mount_Point');
```

This re-establishes the necessary link(?) so that the PHP script can read it again. Re-mounting it from the Finder did not work.